# Rename [unlocking] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [unlocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlocking) wiki says quite clearly that it is for question about ***SIM unlocking***.

However, there have been a *lot* of questions recently where the asker has used "unlocking" to refer to getting past the lock screen. I have been fixing the ones I've seen by changing them to [lock-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lock-screen), but that's not a long-term solution.

Now, I'd be the last person to want to coddle people who don't bother use the many resources that are right in front of them, but we all should know by now that **people don't read on the Internet**.

I suggest that "unlocking" is too generic a term. Perhaps this would fix it:

- Rename [unlocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlocking) to [sim-unlocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-unlocking)
- Create [screen-unlock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-unlock) and [unlock-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlock-screen) as synonyms to [lock-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lock-screen). This will guide the user when they start to type "unlock" in the tags field
- Be on the lookout for re-creation of the [unlocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlocking) or [unlock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlock) tags and rename them to the correct form

Comment: This seems logical to me, as we also have a `bootloader-lock` tag to help disambiguate between that and screen/SIM locks. `unlocking` is just too vague.

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad idea to have a [tag:bootloader-unlock] synonym.

Comment: That's a good thought, I'll create that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done. I ended up performing the following steps:

- Retagged a few questions that were using [unlocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlocking) inappropriately
- Renamed [unlocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlocking) to [sim-unlocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-unlocking)
- Made [sim-locked](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-locked) a synonym of [sim-unlocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-unlocking) since it was only used a few times and always in the same context
- Made [screen-unlock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-unlock) and [unlock-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlock-screen) synonyms of [lock-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lock-screen).